# Weird bug in answer text displayed

Tags: bug, answers

I noticed the following weird discrepancy between the answer text shown in my inbox and the actual post. The answer, as it appears in my inbox, begins "I read once that it stems...". However, when I clicked on the linked answer, it reads "perhaps it stems..." with zero edits (images for both below). Why is that?

[image: inbox]

[image: answer]

Comment: Maybe an edit during the 5 minute grace period?

Comment: @DoubleAA possible (we can probably check with the author), but why wouldn't the inbox pick that up?

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Yes, I admit to changing the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered adequately by others in the comments to the question; I'm just collecting the information here. The answer was edited from "I read…" to "Perhaps…" within five minutes, which generally doesn't show as a separate edit in the answer's history. Your inbox notification must've either arrived before that edit or been based (blame caching) on the pre-edit text.